# How to run jpegs recovery program written in c?

Tags: c, cs50, recover

So I'm a beginner in c and I have succeeded in writing a program for cs50 pset4 that recovers photos more specifically jpeg. However I want to test my program on something else, I mean my own deleted photos. Is it possible? If yes, how? Any help would be appreciated.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Accepts only two command-line arguments (name of the program and name of the file)
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image");
        return 1;
    }

    //Assigning a name to argv[1]
    char *filename = argv[1];

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    // Exiting the program if failed to open argv[1]
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s\n", filename);
        return 2;
    }

    FILE *img = NULL;           // Name of the output file
    bool jpeg_found = false;    // Already found jpeg (false)
    unsigned char buffer[512];  // A buffer or a chunk of memory
    int imgcounter = 0;         // Calculate the number of jpegs

    // Reads the data from the file
    while (fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == true)
    {
        // Checks the condidtions of jpeg
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // If there is already jpeg close it
            if (jpeg_found == true)
            {
                 fclose(img);
            }

            // assign that there is a jpeg
            else
            {
                jpeg_found = true;
            }

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", imgcounter);  // Prints the name of the img files
            img = fopen(filename, "w");                 // Open img to be written
            imgcounter++;
        }

        if (jpeg_found == true)
        {
            fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, img);
        }
    }

    fclose(img);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ehm, just run it?

Comment: I tried many times. Please if you have any experience in this, may you support it with details? You can also try the code if you like. BTW it is working on cs50 card.raw.

Comment: How do you do when you run it? What result do you get? What do you expect instead?

Comment: The file you are recovering the jpg files from is specifically constructed for this assignment.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Any idea how to manipulate the code in such way that I can recover any jpeg files?

Comment: No. This is a simple program to do a specific simple thing.